# Slightly new to c++ and getting the error message "error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token"

Tags: c++, function, class, while-loop

Currently creating a battleship game for my c++ class, I'm working on creating a way in which each ship can be randomly placed on the board. So far I have come up with this, the only issue is that I had ships overlapping each other. To try and fix this I put another condition within my while loop which calls a function to check if the spot is taken. I thought it would all work fine and dandy, but instead, I get this error message and now I'm pretty much stuck.

```
#include "ship.h"
#include "board.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Ship::setShip(Board &board) {
   
    bool isOpen(int x, int y);
    srand(time(0) * (size+rand()));
    int x = rand() % 10;
    int y = rand() % 10;
    int orientation = rand() % 2 == 0 ? 0 : 1;
    string open = "[ ]";

    if (orientation == 0) {
        // check if ship is off the board 
        while (x + size > board.COLS || !isOpen(x, y)) {
            x = rand() % 10;
            y = rand() % 10;
        }
        for (int i = x; i < x + size; i++) {
            board.board[i][y] = shipLetter;
        }
    } else {
        while (y + size > board.ROWS || board.board[x][y] != open) {
            x = rand() % 10;
            y = rand() % 10;
        }
        for (int i = y; i < y + size; i++) {
            board.board[x][i] = shipLetter;
        }
    }
    
    bool isOpen(int x, int y)
    {
        bool taken = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (board.board[x + i][y] != open) {
                taken = true;
            }  else {
            taken = false;
            }
        }
        return taken;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't have a function definition inside another function definition. You need to move `isOpen` out.

Comment: Also, you should call `srand` only once (conventionally, this is done early in `main`), and the complicated seed `time(0) * (size+rand())` doesn't make it more random.

Comment: Further, `rand() % 2 == 0 ? 0 : 1` is equivalent to `rand() % 2`.

Comment: Side note: recommended viewing: [rand() Considered Harmful](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=LDPMpc-ENqY)

Answer (score 0):

Move the function definition `isOpen` outside, and before, the method body of `setShip`. So according to this:

```
...
bool isOpen(int x, int y) { 
   .... full function implementation here
}

void Ship::setShip(Board& board) { 
   // isOpen(int x, int y); <-- remove this line
   .... rest of method implementation here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't define a function inside another function.